# Amazon Cloud Drive for photo backup - how does it handle edited photos?

Tags: photos, backup, synchronization, amazon-cloud-drive

I backed up all my photographs to my cloud drive and then found that there's no way to synchronise photos so they continue to stay updated. (Also read [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/906069/how-do-i-keep-files-synchronized-with-amazon-cloud-drive/906935#906935?newreg=3d3389ec414d43149bd2ced85bf3a028)).  I know that you can drag a file into the Amazon Cloud Drive app and when you do, it skips any duplicates.

As such, if I want to edit/update any photos (i.e. - in Lightroom or Photoshop) and then re-backup my photos so that my cloud drive has the **most recent** version, when I click and drag that file into the app to (re)upload the pictures within, will it replace the edited files with the newest version or just see it as a duplicate and skip it (thereby keeping the old version)?

Comment: If you edit a screenshot, and upload it, it is no longer a duplicate of the photo that already existed.